# Insert a record into foreign table in JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I have entities from tables in database such as:
[image]

You see their relationship is one-to-many
The **IDDot** in **Dot** is an identity column. The **IDMS** in **MaSoDuThuong** is an identity column. In normally, i can insert one record into two tables but in other page I need to insert a record into **MaSoDuThuong** table when i know the value of **IDDot**. Pls help me do!

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSF or Primefaces... are you using JPA or Hibernate framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dot dot = entityManager.getReference(Dot.class, dotId);
MaSoDuThuong m = new MaSoDuThuong();
m.setDot(dot);
em.persist(m);
```

As simple as that.

Comment: Dear @JB-Nizet, i have tried so you guided but it have error **java.lang.NullPointerException**

Comment: Without the code and the full stack trace, what can I do? Why don't you read the stack trace and find to discover what the problem is by yourself? The stack trace should tell you exactly where the exception happens.

Comment: Sorry @JN-Net, i have a crazy in my code. I have done successfully using your help. Thanks a lot!